# Como criar uma API RESTful com processamento e resposta assíncrona usando C# + Angular(v5+)

Tags: c#, angular, restful, async

Olá, estou trabalhando com C# e tenho o seguinte problema:

Imaginem que tenho uma rota para minha API `api/estoque/inventario` onde essa rota deverá fazer o cálculo do inventário de todo o estoque da aplicação e por demanda retornar o resultado. Pra montar essa rota da API, eu teria algo semelhante a isso:

```cs
namespace Api
{
  public class Estoque { ... }

  [Route("api/estoque/inventario")]
  [ApiController]
  public class EstoqueController: ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult<ICollection<Estoque>>> GetInventario()
    {
      try
      {
        // pega os produtos
        // faz todas as regras de negócio (síncronas e assíncronas)
        // retorna o estoque com o inventário (como?)
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

O problema é que, mesmo que eu tenha uma tarefa assíncrona na minha API, a resposta ao meu cliente não é assíncrona. No lado do Cliente, eu uso a biblioteca [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) juntamente com o [Angular](https://angular.io/) e o serviço que faz as requisições para a API tem o retorno de um objeto observável, Assim:

```js
export const API_URL = '...';

export interface IEstoque { ... }

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EstoqueService {

  private baseUrl: string = "/api/estoque";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public getInventario(): Observable<IEstoque[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}${this.baseUrl}/inventario`);
  }

}
```

Minha intenção é usar a lista de itens processados no estoque juntamente com o pipe [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) que existe no angular, que faz com que eu possa fazer um loop assíncrono com base no retorno do serviço, ficando assim:

```html
<div *ngFor='let estoque of estoqueList | async'>
  {{estoque | json}}
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'estoque-list',
  templateUrl: 'estoque-list.component.html',
})
export class EstoqueList {

  public estoqueList: Observable<IEstoque[]>;

  constructor(public estoqueService: EstoqueService) {
    this.estoqueList = estoqueService.getInventario();
  }

}
```

O que eu preciso fazer para que minha rota `api/estoque/inventario` passe a enviar a lista de estoque de forma assíncrona e contínua ao meu frontend com base no processamento?

Comment: Nesse caso pra enviar dados continuos melhor usar websockets. Nao sei como faz em c#.

Comment: Uma coisa eu não entendi, quando você diz que o lado server precisa ser assincrono, por qual motivo?

Você descreveu que quer "fazer o cálculo do inventário de todo o estoque da aplicação e por demanda retornar o resultado", o que seria esse por demanda?

Você quer uma aplicação que fique escutando e conforme vão surgindo novos dados em estoque ele já vá exibindo nessa aplicação em tempo "real"?

Comment: A declaração da sua *api* está correta, agora precisa ver o restando do código dentro dela. Todas as chamadas em cadeia, em todas as camadas/projetos que você tiver uma chamada a partir da sua *api* devem retornar tasks `async`, e ser chamadas usando o `await`, ou não irão funcionar corretamente de forma assíncrona

Comment: O que estou precisando fazer é o que o Eduardo disse, como websockets, só que não faço idéia de como fazer isso em C#

Comment: Essa seria uma atualização em realtime Juliano. A apicação em si é uma aplicação de controle de logística e isso precisa ter uma gestão em realtime.

Comment: Sim Ricardo, eu tenho ciência disso, tanto que estou gerando uma Api e não uma camada de acesso direto a dados.

Comment: Uai, não entendi sua dúvida, já não estão assíncronas as chamas no serviço e o método no C#?

Comment: Mesmo que as chamadas estejam assíncronas no serviço, o retorno do conteúdo não é assíncrono, eu tenho que processar todos os dados antes de retornar. A intenção é que eu possa retornar aos poucos, creio que como o Eduardo disse com websockets

Comment: Se vc souber um pouco de nodejs recomendo o https://socket.io/

Comment: eu tenho costume de trabalhar com socket.io em NodeJS, o problema é que o pessoa da empresa onde trabalho não quer trocar de tecnologia, portanto sou obrigado a usar C# + ASPNETCore + Angular...

Comment: Por mais que você faça um flush parcial e observando o stream da resposta, ainda assim o que você receberia seria um Json, incompleto e inválido. Se você deseja um broadcast em tempo real vai precisar mudar completamente a sua arquitetura.

Comment: eu tava até vendo aqui sobre o Broadcast do Laravel, o que ele e o Socket.io faz é o que eu to procurando

Comment: Caso você queira trabalhar via websockets, pode utilizar signalr no .net e fazer a comunicação. asp.net/signalr. No angular ja tem bibliotecas de signalr tambem.

Comment: @porfavorexcluirconta quando digo que preciso enviar de forma assíncrona é porque não posso fazer tudo e depois mandar... Minha ideia é mandar sempre que tiver completado um item do estoque para que não trave a aplicação em ambos os lados

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu fazer isso não garante que o envio para o cliente será assíncrono, ou seja, por finalização de cálculo

Answer (score 2):

Leandro, a assinatura da sua API está assíncrona. Isso quer dizer que nessa parte (assinatura do método) ela está correta. Mas vamos revisar algumas coisas aqui, que podem estar interferindo com o que você deseja.

## 1 - Todo o fluxo deve ser assíncrono.

Quando se trabalha de forma síncrona, tudo deve ser síncrono. Igualmente, quando se trabalha assíncrono, tudo deve ser assíncrono. Isso porque misturar os comportamentos traz resultados indesejados. Portanto, verifique se todo o código, o fluxo de obtenção de dados e todo o processamento também são assíncronos, não apenas a assinatura do seu método. PS: jogar tudo dentro de `Task.Factory.StartNew` não é um caminho...

## 2 - A palavra-chave `async` na sua API não torna o HTTP assíncrono.

Vale lembrar que o HTTP em si não é assíncrono. Ou seja, o seu cliente (JavaScript) vai sempre esperar pela resposta do servidor e mesmo que o seu método na API seja assíncrono, a sua interface não necessariamente será.
Usar async na assinatura do método está relacionado aos internos de requisição/resposta, alocação de threads de recepção de chamadas e I/O, e não a permitir que a sua interface seja mais responsiva. Basicamente, usar async deixa sua API mais leve e mais escalável, especialmente quando ela precisa "seguir" para tarefas mais lentas (como buscar dados num banco de dados).

Isso quer dizer que o cliente (JavaScript) vai, sim, esperar todo o processamento ocorrer e finalmente receber a resposta. A diferença é que enquanto o cliente espera, a thread de I/O que ficaria travada esperando a resposta (e essa thread pertence a um grupo com quantidade finita) não vai ficar travada e poderá ser usada para outras requisições (mais rápidas, por exemplo). Mas o cliente permanecerá aguardando até que todo o processamento esteja concluído e o resultado seja retornado pela sua API.

## 3 - Então como melhorar a experiência?

Existem vários métodos e não há uma resposta em definitivo porque cada cenário tem uma saída diferente. Em alguns casos, uma tela "loading" (indicando o carregamento) já basta. Em outros pode ser necessário usar SignalR ou SocketIO para enviar dados à medida que forem disponibilizados. Em outros cenários você pode criar uma tarefa de processamento e retornar uma espécie de ID que poderá consultar mais tarde (de tempos em tempos) para saber se já foi concluída. Tudo depende do que exatamente você quer, dos requisitos do projeto (e do cliente) e do tempo total de processamento esperado. Da mesma forma que é intolerável deixar um "loading..." travado por 4h para processar os dados, é irreal criar toda uma estrutura SignalR para uma tarefa que leva 1 segundo para ser processada.

Comment: eu estou acostumado a usar isso com socket.io no Laravel e também NodeJS mas não encontrei nenhum código "legível" e simples de entender para implementar esse recurso de forma aceitável e escalável...

Comment: @LeandroLuk Como o cliente depende de uma conexão aberta com o servidor para que comunicação em tempo real aconteça, de duas, uma: ou você criará um API-Gateway ou Proxy ou similar que será responsável por receber as conexões e realizar chamadas internas, ou o seu gateway/proxy/etc deverá compreender e promover um fixation de forma que as chamadas sejam sempre redirecionadas ao mesmo servidor em um farm.

Comment: eu pensei em prover isso usando Websocket's, onde eu implementaria o mesmo junto ao método HTTP HEAD, onde ele por si só serviria pra me dizer o os status do conteúdo... a idéia é fazer algo como o firebase faz...

Comment: Do lado do cliente está certo. Do lado do servidor, o Firebase está usando um gateway que redistribui as tarefas em vários nós de servidores replicados. Se você vai fazer o servidor "escalável" também, tem que pensar do lado dele também, não só do cliente da aplicação :)

Answer (score -1):

Quando usamos Api, nós fazemos requisições, quando o método é async ele não mandará nada assíncrono para você como respostas ao usuário, e como trabalhamos com request em API, não possuiremos nada constante, para isso você deverá pesquisar sobre SocketI que fará isso melhor a sua necessidade, hoje em 2019 uma das novidades da Microsoft é o RazorComponent, que fará uma aplicação WEB usando o SignalR e tals assim você ficara realmente ligado ao seu BackEnd podendo fazer esse método assíncrono que precisa.